# kibana warning on Elasticsearch plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I just installed and am running ElasticSearch (customized version)/Kibana as below:

```
ES: 5.1.1
Kibana: 6.0.1
CentOS: 7.3
```

After I started Kibana it shows me an warning below:
This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v6.0.1 on all nodes. I found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: v5.1.1 @ 127.0.0.1:9200 (127.0.0.1)

so I proceed to download the lastest version of ElasticSearch 7.2.0

I restarted ES and confirmed it is running on 7.2, I restarted Kibana and it is still showing the warning but warning shows the ES version is 7.2 yet it still complains version is low.

> This version of Kibana requires Elasticsearch v6.0.1 on all nodes. I
>   found the following incompatible nodes in your cluster: v7.2.0 @
>   127.0.0.1:9200 (127.0.0.1)

Does it mean I have to install a different version of Kibana/elasticsearch instead of the latest?

How do I get this fixed?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have the answer now as per this compatibility matrix:

https://www.elastic.co/support/matrix#matrix_compatibility

I am downloading new Kibana and see if it works, I will update here so this post serves something for whoever read it later.

UPDATE: I just confirmed this is the root cause and now it is not showing any warning like that.